# Correlation of an approximation over a random permutation

Tags: linear-cryptanalysis

I read a paper of linear cryptanalysis that is J.Daemen et al's [Probability distribution of correlation and differentials in block cipher](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/212.pdf).

In this paper's lemma 8's proof, I can't understand this formula (page.13).

> The number of balanced Boolean functions $g(a)$ for a given value of $x$ is :
>
> $$ {{2^{n-1}} \choose {2^{n-2}+x}} {{2^{n-1}} \choose {2^{n-2}-x}} = {{2^{n-1}} \choose {2^{n-2}+x}}^2$$
>   and
>
> If we divide this by the total number of balanced Boolean functions,..."

Please, tell me how this formula is derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $x$ measures the departure from balance in the left half of the truth table, say it is the excess number of 1's in the left half of length $2^{n-1}$. By the definition of binomial coefficients there are $$\binom{2^{n-1}}{2^{n-2}+x}$$ such vectors. This is the first factor. The second factor is the count of vectors missing $x$ 1's, since the overall truth table is balanced.

Using $$\binom{a}{b}=\binom{a}{a-b}$$ completes the argument.

Comment: Why the probability is computed by only g(a)? u, v, alpha don't affect probability?

Comment: Yes it is. Read the discussion preceding equation (20) starting in the previous page.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Perhaps you can upvote the answer, if you liked it :-)